# Adding a dial on an Alert Dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am currently trying to make an AlertDialog in Android Studio.

I have the basic gist of making a basic AlertDialog with a few buttons and a message, but I want to add an additional function that shows a 'dial' on the dialog.

[image: This is the sort of dialog format I want to make.]

The question is, how do I achieve this dial effect?

I am aware that I am able to simply list down a few choices and move on, but if this is not too complicated, then I would prefer this way.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Try this : https://github.com/CiTuX/datetimepicker

Answer (score 1):

You can use the system time picker dialog.
[Official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html) and [Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html).

Comment: While the link might provide the correct answer, it's best to comment the code so in case the website get's removed your answer is still valid.